# Ajax call showing multiple records from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax call that looks like so;

```
success: function(data) {

        //Return the results of the campaign data and populate the page.

         $(data).find('campaign').each(function(i) {

            campaignTitle = $(data).find('campaignTitle').text(),
            campaignDesc = $(data).find('campaignDesc').text(),
            campaignType = $(data).find('campaignType').text(),
            campaignStatus = $(data).find('campaignStatus').text(),
            campaignDuration = $(data).find('duration').text(),
            campaignAuthor = $(data).find('whoCreated').text(),
            campaignCreated = $(data).find('dateCreated').text(),
            campaignTypeText = $(data).find('type').text(),
            campaignDataID = $(data).find('typeID').text(),
            campaignTypeName = $(data).find('typeName').text();

         });
```

There are 2 records being returned but the only difference in the 2 is the Data ID which I get from a relational join in my table.

My page is a single "record" with campaign details on it.

For example, there is a title of the campaign.

```
$('[name=campaignTitle]').empty().append(campaignTitle);
```

Now because its returning multiple records, its duplicating the campaign title which I understand that it will do that.

Since all of the data is the same in the rows except the data ID's, I only need to show everything one time and then I would keep the multiple ID's that it returns and do something with them.

I am trying to do something like so :

```
campaignTitle = $(data).find('campaignTitle')[0].text(),
```

This returns undefined.

In short, I only want the campaign title to show one time, even if there are 5 records and I would do this by specifying  which it as [0] since I know it would be the same as 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return a DataSet or DataTable in your return and break down the value-pairs?